# Android animation ease in effect

Tags: android, animation

Hi does anyone know how to add an ease in effect to an animation?

heres my animation so far

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ease in?" If you mean start out fast and get slower as it gets closer to the end, then what you want is a decelerate_interpolator instead of the accelerate_interpolator